# Bot Telegram php: Conversation with a specific user

Tags: php, bots, telegram

After this step:

```
if($message == "Bot copy me")
{
    sendMessage($chatid, "Sure?");
}
```

How a bot can reply to this specific user that said "Bot copy me" if he say "yes", for example, and copy him until he say "stop" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your own database. If you don't have one, the easiest way is use file.

For instance, use `file_get_contents("/tmp/tg-bot-{$chatid}-status")` to get status. When received `Sure`, use `file_put_contents("/tmp/tg-bot-{$chatid}-status", "REPLY")` to set.